# Understanding Scala lazy val inheritance rules

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

In this code, `x` is null during construction:

```
abstract class A {
    val x: String
    println(s"A: x is $x")
}

class B extends A {
    val x: String = "foo"
    println(s"B: x is $x")    
}

new B()
```

```
A: x is null
B: x is foo
```

It can be fixed by adding `lazy` to the declaration of `x` in `B`:

```
abstract class A {
    val x: String
    println(s"A: x is $x")
}

class B extends A {
    lazy val x: String = "foo"
    println(s"B: x is $x")    
}

new B()
```

```
A: x is foo
B: x is foo
```

I don't understand exactly why. It's counterintuitive that making a val `lazy` should cause it to be initialized *earlier* than the corresponding non-lazy val would have been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementing `val` definition in a subclass is evaluated - only after- its superclass has been initialized. Since you require the evaluation of the `val` before the superclass has finished initialization, the JVM knowns it's not yet initialized so it gives you the default value for an uninitialized `String`, which is `null`.

This is one of the reasons why `lazy val`s were built into the language:
When you prefix a `val` definition with the `lazy` modifier, the initializing expression on the right-hand side will only be evaluated the first time the `val` is used. Since you require the `val` to be evaluated in the superclass, it triggers it's evaluation. That is why it becomes available in the superclass.

Comment: Thanks. I modified my question to make my confusion more clear, BTW. I guess `lazy` doesn't always imply that initialization happens _later_ than it otherwise would have.

Comment: It is counterintuitive to ask for the value of a `val` before initialization. *Lazy evaluation* is also called *call-by-need*. You *needed* it before the initialization line. `Lazy` does not necessarily means *later*, but means *let the system decide when things should be initialized*.